# Onomatopée(s) représentant le bruit que fait une personne qui engloutit/mastique bruyamment sa nourriture : nuances de « glouglou » ?

Tags: alimentation, onomatopées, japonais

On explique que le nom du personnage [*Pac-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man_(character)) (du jeu vidéo bien connu de Namco), est basé à l'origine sur la langue japonaise : « *paku-paku* (パクパク), an onomatopoeic Japanese word for [gobbling something up](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/gobble/583878) » (Wikipedia EN : initialement translittéré [*Puckman*](https://youtu.be/EhwKDnWkcCk)), essentiellement une onomatopée pour *engloutir* quelque nourriture. On connaît le *glouglou* familièrement pour le « bruit d'un liquide s'échappant du goulot d'une bouteille, ou tout bruit analogue » (Larousse ; ou pour le *cri du dindon*), qu'on associe facilement au fait de boire (un liquide) ou peut-être même au bruit qu'on fait en le buvant. L'onomatopée pour *engloutir* s'appuie-t-elle sur celle de *boire* ?

---

- Quelle est l'onomatopée représentant le bruit que fait une personne
  qui *engloutit ou avale tout rond* sa nourriture ; peut-on produire des exemples provenant de sources crédibles ?
- Y a-t-il une onomatopée distincte pour le fait de *mastiquer
  bruyamment* ; cette onomatopée est-elle toujours tributaire de la *composition* de l'aliment mastiqué, ou bien plutôt de l'intensité de l'action ?
- Y a-t-il un lien entre l'une ou l'autre onomatopée et le *glouglou* ?

---

L'exemple qui suit sert à illustrer le genre de contexte dans lequel s'articulent mes questions, dont celles formulées ci-dessus suite à ma lecture de l'origine du nom du personnage du *Pac-Man* :

> On pouvait l'[entendre](https://youtu.be/MJwCyuFEZm0) de l'autre bout du labyrinthe successivement ingurgiter une *root beer* (1) en mangeant des tranches de pomme (2), puis ensuite copieusement mastiquer chaque grains de fromage en grains (3) qu'il trouva avant d'avaler tout rond le restant de la poutine (4), fantômes inclus :
>
> > [Glou-glou](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/glouglou/37233?q=glouglou#37179) (1) — [cric-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cric-crac)/[crac](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crac)/[croc](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/croc/1)/« crounche » (*crunch* ?) (2) — « [skouik-skouik](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fromage_en_grains) » ([couic](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couic) ?) (3) — glou (4) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CNRTL(TFLi)(REM. 3.) note un usage (d’accord, vieux et rare) de :

> [« **Gargoter**, verbe intrans. … c) Vx et rare. Faire du bruit en
>   **déglutissant**. C'est d'puis midi qu'i gargotte comme ça (MAUPASS., Contes et nouv., t. 1, Vieux, 1884, p. 132)
>   »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gargoter) ...

...avec une référence à la fin de la page à « la racine onomat. garg- (gargouille*) ».

CNRTL(DMF) aussi en fait référence  avec ["Faire du bruit avec la gorge"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/gargoter).

Comme anglophone, tout ça me fait penser (comme *glou-glou* d’ailleurs) plutôt aux liquides qu’à la nourriture (via *gargle*, le mot anglais), mais vu que **déglutir/déglutissant** = « Faire passer les **aliments** et la salive de la bouche à l'estomac, par le canal de l'œsophage » (CNRTL [TFLi]), peut-être « gargoter » marche (ou plutôt « marchait ») pour la bouffe aussi.

---

Surtout pas pour soutenir ma réponse (et c’est plutôt le contraire, vu que « gargoter » ne figure pas du tout dedans !), mais je vous conseille fortement :
  [*LA TRADUCTION DES ONOMATOPÉES DANS LA BANDE DESSINÉE*](http://bd-fle.wikispaces.com/file/view/La%20traduction%20des%20onomatop%C3%A9es%20dans%20la%20bande%20dessin%C3%A9e.pdf) par SELJA SEPPÄLÄ,

qui traite, exhaustivement, les onomatopées anglaises  (et leurs équivalents, traductions, et/ou calques/inventions françaises) employées dans la BD *Garfield*.

A propos votre question, il y a « SCHLRP » (pp. 53 et XXXV) et « SLRP » (pp. 39 et XXXVI) qui ont l’air d’avoir été inventés/calqués  pour « MANGER/ENGLOUTISSEMENT » ;
 et puis « GLOUP » et « GLUP » (p. XXXII) aussi pour « MANGER/ENGLOUTISSEMENT » (qui ressemblent à « glou[-glou] », avec un « p » ajouté).

« SCROMP » et (proposé ailleurs) « SCRO/UNCH » (p. XXXV) et même « SRONCH » (p. XXXVI) se servent aussi pour « MANGER/ENGLOUTISSEMENT », mais vu la ressemblance à
[« CRUNCH », le mot anglais que vous mentionnez](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crunch)  (=“ to crush hard food loudly between the teeth” [from *Cambridge Dictionary*]) ...

**et** la connexion avec  « CROQUEMENT » notée par l’auteur à page 14, je trouve que « SCRONCH » (ainsi que « SCRUNCH » et « SRONCH ») marcheraient bien aussi pour « mastiquer bruyamment ».

(Please see also the charts on pages 10, 92, and 93 as well as the relevant entries on the charts on pages III, V, and XI for direct connections made between the French and English versions of the "words" mentioned above)

Comment: Merci, ce que vous présentez du document est fort intéressant, et les tableaux à la fin autorisent plusieurs réflexions stimulantes, le tout en 180 pp. en _comic sans_, faut le faire ! Il y a de l'anglais dans mes onomatopées, de sorte qu'avant d'écrire _glou_ dans mon exemple j'avais écrit _gulp_ ; aussi j'ai de la difficulté à imaginer le son du truc qui croustille autrement qu'avec _crunch_. Enfin j'ai remarqué que je dis systématiquement _whoop(s)_ /whooppe-laille (i.e. oupelaille) alors que ma grand-mère (ne parle pas l'anglais) dit _oupe_ sans "w"... Pareil mais différent. Merci !

Comment: @のｂるしｔｙぱんｋｙ "... le tout en 180 pp. en *comic sans* ... ." Mince, je n'ai meme pas fait la connexion! Comme vous dites: faut le faire!  Et puis pour parler encore des “glouglous”, peut-être vous connaissez [cette chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VszFIyk5eI) qui en a à plusieurs reprises. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Une recherche fournit, par exemple :

http://edit.artdesign.free.fr/onomatopee.htm

> MANGER: (aliments liquides, soupe...) SLURP ; SLUUUUURP ; (aliments solides) SCRUNCH ; SCROTCH ; CRATCH-CRATCH ; (de bon appétit) MIAM-MIAM .

Comment: Peut-on svp. expliquer et préciser si l'on pense qu'elles s'appliquent à _engloutir_, et peut-être aussi trouver des exemples dans la littérature. Merci.

Comment: @のｂるしｔｙぱんｋｙ: « slurp » s'applique tout à fait à « engloutir » de même que « scrunch » qui ont tous deux une connotation négative/bruyante

Answer (score 2):

***Miam-miam*** est une onomatopée que l'on retrouve dans [la plupart des langues du monde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias#Food_being_eaten), plus souvent sous la forme « niam-niam » ou « nam-nam ». Elle évoque le bruit émis par une personne dont la bouche s'ouvre et se referme lors de la mastication.

Curieusement, « miam-miam » a perdu au moins en français son caractère onomatopéique et n'est aujourd'hui qu'une interjection utilisée pour évoquer le plaisir associé à l'absorption de nourriture.

Existent aussi, plus rares, l'onomatopée « [**happ**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/happ) » décrivant le bruit des mâchoires attrapant un aliment et qui a donné le verbe « happer » ainsi que « **baff** » évoquant le gonflement des joues et qui a donné le verbe « [bâfrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2frer) ».

Alors que l'absorption de liquide renvoie à l'onomatopée [glou-glou](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/glou-glou), dont on retrouve des [équivalents très proches dans beaucoup d'autres langues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias#Liquid_being_drunk). Il n'existe pas d'onomatopée établie pour décrire le bruit précis de déglutition de nourriture solide.

On peut néanmoins signaler toute la famille de mots tels que [gorge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gorge), gargouiller, gargantua, gargariser, ingurgiter, etc. dérivée du latin *gurga/gurges*, du grec ancien *[γαργαρίζω](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gargarizo#Latin)* (gargarizo « gargariser ») que l'on retrouve aussi dans *γαργαρεών* gargareôn (« luette ») et en sanskrit (*[गर्गर](http://sanskritdictionary.com/gargara/70784/1)* *gargara*) dont l'origine vraisemblablement commune est une onomatopée très ancienne évoquant le bruit d'un tourbillon.

Comment: Votre réponse mérite davantage qu'un vote à mon avis. Cependant je ne peux voter deux fois. Merci !

Comment: Merci pour le commentaire. Pour être franc, avant de faire des recherches sur « miam-miam », j'étais plutôt sceptique sur une origine purement onomatopéique mais l'abondance de mots similaires dans des langues n'ayant aucun lien entre elles ne permet pas de doute. C'est aussi la première fois de ma vie que je cite du sanskrit dans le texte ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Selon Wikipedia l'*[interjection](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection#Interjection_et_syntaxe)*, est une catégorie de mot invariable, permettant au sujet parlant de réaliser — approximativement — une image sonore d'un événement (cri d'animal, explosion, bruit quelconque, etc.).

Ainsi, selon cette représentation le bruit que fait une personne qui mange est:

> miam-miam

Mais manger est bien moins intense que "engloutir", "dévorer", ...

Comment: À mon sens, « Miam-miam » est plus une invitation à manger qu'une onomatopée représentant l'action de manger.

Comment: La question posée porte sur le bruit que fait une personne qui engloutit sa nourriture (engloutir apporte une connotation négative) ou qui mastique bruyamment (connotation franchement négative). [Miam-miam](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/miam-miam) est l'onomatopée qui indique que quelque chose est appétissant et donc la connotation est très positive et de toute façon ne représente pas le bruit de la déglutition.

Comment: @Laure Dans ce que j'ai écris, j'ai fais référence à manger et non pas à engloutir comme vous le dites. Quant à la connotation positive/négative, c'est tout à fait relatif.

Comment: @Toto « Miam-miam » Invitation à manger? C'est dans quelle langue?

Comment: La question  posée ne porte pas sur le bruit qu'on fait en mangeant simplement mais "le bruit que fait une personne qui engloutit ou avale tout rond sa nourriture" et  "le fait de mastiquer bruyamment".

Comment: Quel est-il alors?

Comment: Effectivement, ce n'est pas vraiment une invitation à manger, c'est une interjection prononcée lorsqu'on se régale mais certainement pas une onomatopée représentant le bruit que l'on fait lorsqu'on mange.

Comment: C'est exactement ce que j'ait éecrit

Comment: Non, tu dis que « Miam-miam » est une représentation du bruit que fait une personne qui mange. Je n'ai jamais entendu une personne faire le bruit « Miam-miam » lorsqu'elle mange.

Comment: @Toto Moi si, et c'est d'ailleurs l'onomatopée retenue par [une majorité de langues dans le monde pour décrire ce son.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias#Food_being_eaten)

Comment: On vous invite tous à multiplier les réponses. Merci !